# 2 plotshape in 2 lines

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

This code make plotshape on the top of the chart.  Perfect.

```
maType = input.string(title='SSL1 / Baseline Type', defval='HMA', options=['HMA'])
len = input(title='SSL1 / Baseline Length', defval=60)
src = close

ma(type, src, len) =>
    float result = 0
    if type == 'HMA'  // Hull
        result := ta.wma(2 * ta.wma(src, len / 2) - ta.wma(src, len), math.round(math.sqrt(len)))
        result
    
///Keltner Baseline Channel
BBMC = ma(maType, close, len)
multy = input.float(0.2, step=0.05, title='Base Channel Multiplier')
Keltma = ma(maType, src, len)
range_1 = high - low
rangema = ta.ema(range_1, len)
upperk = Keltma + rangema * multy
lowerk = Keltma - rangema * multy

//COLORS
color_bar = close > upperk ? #00c3ff : close < lowerk ? #ff0062 : na

//PLOTS
plotshape((close > upperk), style=shape.triangleup, color = #00ff0a, location = location.top)
plotshape((close < lowerk), style=shape.triangleup, color = #ff0000, location = location.top)
```

The problem is that i have another code like this (with a different setup) and a second plotshape.

How is it possible to put the second plotshape in a another line just below the first one ?

I have ty with table.cell but i don't know how i can add plot in the table.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `location.absolute` and calculate the `y` location yourself. Using the `atr` is a nice option usually.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

offset=input(1)
atr = ta.atr(14)

loc1 = high + atr
loc2 = loc1 + (offset * atr)

plotshape(loc1, "1", shape.circle, location.absolute, color.green)
plotshape(loc2, "2", shape.diamond, location.absolute, color.red)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for the code.

I will try this but it will be not "fixed" on the top.

I try to put in table but without success.

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution.

```
plotshape(loc1 ? 0 : na, "", style=shape.square, location=location.absolute
```